# Is it a wise decision to store JSON webtoken in LocalStorage/Session Storage in Angular 6?

Tags: angular

I have read many links which discuss about the usage of storing JSON web token in local storage/session storage/cookie and their pros and cons.

Experienced developers prefer to use it in Cookies.But my question is how safe is it to store it in local storage/session storage if I am using Angular 6.

As there has been recent updates in Angular and now we have Angular 6 ,so is Angular 6 safe from XSS attack. CSRF attack is something which will not be a risk if I am using local storage/session storage.

To be precise can I use a JSON web token in local storage/session storage if I am using Angular 6.

Thanks
Sachin

Comment: `can you use` : yes. `Are cookies safer` : no. `is Angular safe from XSS` : no, but it's very hard to perform because of minification, and because you use an API, you have a second level of security. `How safe to store in local storage` : you don't care, it's only a token. And either way, the user has access to it, let it be local storage or cookie.

Comment: Ok got it. So if my JSON web token only has the user id in the payload then there is no harm to store it in localStorage as there there is no sensitive information in the payload of json web token.Is that correct ?

Comment: your token can contain whatever you want : only your API can generate them (thanks to the signature). So even if someone decodes it and discovers his roles, he wouldn't be able to change them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you need to, because if you use **Interceptors** in Angular for HTTP communication, you cannot inject a service to provide Bearer Token. Because your service needs to communicate with API using HTTP and Interceptors are also **HTTP Handlers**. So there should be another way of providing Bearer Token where needed, which is local storage and every JS client have access to LocalStorage.

Source: [Angular Security Using JSON Web Tokens](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-security-json-web-tokens/table-of-contents)